# Whitespaces when i create tables with SQL

Tags: java, sql, whitespace, removing-whitespace

When i create a table with SQL using Java and JDBC i get get undesired whitespace.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers(name char(15), lname char(15), adress char(15))
```

When i put something in the columns that consists of less characters than the column allows, whitespace is added to the input.

```
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'Somestreet')
```

So `'John'` becomes `'John           '` with eleven whitespace characters.
This is a big problem when it comes to further statements. From what i know you can use `LIKE` but i want to prevent issues with entries like `'John-Paul'`. So i would like to know if you can help me to fix the problem.

My Java code would be something like this:

```
PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Customers SET lname=? WHERE name=?");
prep.setString(1, "Example");
prep.setString(2, "John"); // this doesn't work
prep.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Use a different column type, like `TEXT` or `VARCHAR`.

Comment: As pointed by Sotirios, this is one of the differences between CHAR and VARCHAR...

Comment: The above suggestions are correct. If, for whatever reason, you can't change table structure, you can use `RTRIM()` function in your query.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you i havent thought about column types at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Java: database type `char(length)` is used to specify fixed-length strings, which are padded with whitespace on retrieval to the desired length when the data stored in them has fewer characters than is specified at the definition.

To address this problem, use a data type that is appropriate for variable-length strings, i.e. a `varchar`, `nvarchar`, or `text`:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers(
    name   nvarchar(15)
,   lname  nvarchar(15)
,   adress nvarchar(15)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Char data type is fixed length so if you say 15 it will *alwasy* be 15. If you want "strings you can trim" Use VarChar. You can still make max of 15, but the actual length will be the length of the string inserted.

Comment: Oops. And I see some comments that basically say the same thin in the post.

Comment: "And I see some comments that basically say the same thin in the post" Don't worry about it, that is very common. Some participants prefer to submit a short comment rather than elaborating on the point in a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use varchar(15) or nvarchar(15) instead of char because char data type is fixed length.